# How to encrypt / decrypt binary data in .NET 6.0 with AES in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt binary data with AES in .Net 6.0. Unfortunately, the decryption does not bring back the original data:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes)
{
    using (var aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create())
    {
        byte[] cipherBytes;

        using (MemoryStream cipherStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cipherStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            cipherStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            cipherBytes = new byte[cipherStream.Length];
            cipherStream.Read(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
        }

        byte[] wrongPlainBytes;
        using (MemoryStream cipherStream = new MemoryStream(cipherBytes))
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cipherStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            wrongPlainBytes = cipherStream.ToArray();
        }

        bool shouldBeTrue = plainBytes.Equals(wrongPlainBytes);

        return cipherBytes;
    }
}
```

After executing this code, `shouldBeTrue` should be `true`, but it's `false`. Also, `plainBytes.Length` is different from `wrongPlainBytes.Length`.

**What do I wrong while encryption / decryption?**

Comment: The problem is that `plainBytes.Equals(wrongPlainBytes)` is false because `Equals` does a reference equals in the background, try with `Enumerable.SequenceEquals` i.e `plainBytes.SequenceEquals(wrongPlainBytes)`

Comment: @MindSwipe: `plainBytes.SequenceEqual(wrongPlainBytes)` gives `false` back too.

Comment: Yup, because that was just one problem, another is that you're using `cipherStream.Length` to create the `wrongPlainBytes`, but you haven't written anything to `ciphgerStream` because `cipherBytes` holds no elements

Comment: Just use one of the examples available, even from the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-6.0. Note how they manage writing and reading to crypto streams.

Comment: @Evk: The off. Doc works with `string`, but I want to work with `byte[]`.

Comment: @MindSwipe: Thank you for your hint. I modified the related code in my question, but I still have problems. Why is the `wrongPlainBytes.Length` smaller than `plainBytes.Length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static byte[] Encrypt( byte[] plainBytes )
{
    using ( var aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create() )
    {
        byte[] cipherBytes;

        using ( MemoryStream cipherStream = new MemoryStream() )
        using ( CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream( cipherStream, aes.CreateEncryptor( aes.Key, aes.IV ), CryptoStreamMode.Write ) )
        {

            cryptoStream.Write( plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length );
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            cipherBytes = cipherStream.ToArray();



        }
        byte[] wrongPlainBytes;
        using ( MemoryStream cipherStream = new MemoryStream() )
        using ( CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream( cipherStream, aes.CreateDecryptor( aes.Key, aes.IV ), CryptoStreamMode.Write ) )
        {
            cryptoStream.Write( cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length );
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            wrongPlainBytes = cipherStream.ToArray();

        }

        bool shouldBeTrue = plainBytes.SequenceEqual( wrongPlainBytes );

        return cipherBytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock() did solve my problem.

Comment: cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock() solved my problem too. I have not seen this in any AES binary example. It may be obvious, but I did try flush(). That didn't work, probably due to the fact that it just completed the last bytes of the input, not the padding. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid direct `Read` on streams where possible - this operation is not guaranteed to read the amount of bytes you requested, so when you do use it - you need to check the return value (which you ignore) to figure out *actual* number of bytes that were read, and then act accordingly (do more reads if that amount is less than what you need).

There are several issues in your code, which you can avoid this way:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes)
{
    using (var aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create())
    {
        byte[] cipherBytes;

        using (MemoryStream cipherStream = new MemoryStream()) {
            // use leaveOpen parameter here, that way it will NOT dispose cipherStream when closing cryptoStream
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cipherStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write, true)) {
                // just write
                cryptoStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            }
            // now, cryptoStream is disposed, so we can be sure all data is propertly written to the cipherStream
            // no need to flush or anything
            
            // do not manage buffer yourself, use ToArray
            cipherBytes = cipherStream.ToArray();
        }

        byte[] wrongPlainBytes;
        using (MemoryStream cipherStream = new MemoryStream(cipherBytes)) {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cipherStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
                using (var output = new MemoryStream()) {
                    // same story here, avoid direct reads, use CopyTo, it will copy all data, decrypted, to memory stream
                    cryptoStream.CopyTo(output);

                    // again, just ToArray to avoid manage buffer directly
                    wrongPlainBytes = output.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        bool shouldBeTrue = plainBytes.SequenceEqual(wrongPlainBytes);

        return cipherBytes;
    }
}
```